# Linux programs that offer heartbeat monitoring for process management?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, process, monitoring, heartbeat

We have a Java process on Linux (Ubuntu) that runs as a HTTP server. We've created an endpoint on this process to respond to ping messages on `http://myserver/ping`... a successful response returns `"Ok"` indicating the server process is running.

We want to monitor the http process using a pinging service, preferably one that runs on the same physical server to support kill/restart if necessary, but we don't want to implement this monitor ourselves since there are countless Linux programs that offer monitoring services, but there's so many we're not sure which one is best suited for our needs, so we've listed our requirements. Any pointers to monitoring programs that would best suit our needs would be greatly appreciated, ty

1) Free and package-based (we're not looking for enterprise-grade software)

2) Monitor must support sending http request and acknowledging a response on a regular interval (every 10s, 5m, etc)

3) Must support retry logic (if no response after 10 attempts, kill process by pid, then restart)

4) Must support alerts by email (if no response after 3 attempts, send email to admin@foo.com)

Comment: Nagios? Though that's probably an overkill in this situation.

Comment: So far `monit` appears to be a good fit, but would like to know if other folks with experience can speak to it, Nagios don't look bad either

Comment: You can try out [nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) or monit

Answer (score 1):

Extending comment from Daniel.  Monitoring is only part of the work. Ability to [take actions like restarting the services/machines](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/eventhandlers.html) etc should be really considered as essential to monitoring. we use [nagios](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/) to cover hundreds of machines and services. Proved to be great differentiator.

License is GPL, support is optional.

Comment: Is Nagios free, or requires a support contract?

Comment: License is GPL, support is optional.(answer edited to indicate it). We  do not use support - Before you start check if the terms of use fits you- http://www.nagios.org/legal/termsofuse/

Answer (score 0):

You may also find [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/) useful. It's quite capable but will be easier to set up than Nagios for a simple setup like yours. It has an "actions" mechanism which will allow you to send e-mail alerts or to run a restart script when a trigger fires and it also features some nice built-in graphing functionality which can give you a quick overview of the system's condition.